# Flutter audioplayers apk release does not work

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk, device

I am using Audioplayers Flutter Library for playing assets sound from `assets/sounds/my_sound.mp3`. I'm using AudioCache like this :

```
AudioCache.play(mysound)
```

I am calling this inside a onpressed method from a Raised Button.
It's working find when I am playing my sound in the application from my emulator or my device when I was running

```
flutter run
```

Working fine.

Now, I generate apk with

```
flutter build apk
```

I'm getting the app_release.apk and download it inside my device.
Now, I am trying to launch the application. The app load assets images and other contents. But when I'm trying to play a sound, nothing happened...

I am trying to import apk without Google play store for now because I want test my app in production environments.

What's happened? Can I see a log inside my device for debugging the app?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I think I have the same issue, everything work on the emulator but once I try to run the app on device I can't hear any sound. In your case, does it work while still in debug but running on device? Because if it's not working there you'll be able to check logs.

Answer (score 1):

there is a few Libraries for play audio in app, i introduce them to you:

> assets_audio_player
>
> Audio Player / Audio Players / Audio Player 2
>
> Flute Music Player
>
> Fluttery Audio
>
> Stereo
>
> Music Player

but they have other issue for you

You can use one of them related to your work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you playing audio from assets using AudioCache,
try to set your AudioPlayer on mode: `PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY`

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY);
```

Answer (score -3):

Add full path instead of file name

**Incorret:** AudioCache.play(sample.mp3)

**Correct:** AudioCache.play(assets/sample.mp3)

Comment: Your 'correct' and 'incorrect' examples are exactly the same...